# Parsing NSString

Tags: parsing, time, nsstring, nsdate

I am currently at the point to where I want to create a simple text file, read it into my application, convert the string "0700 1300" to an NSDate format to be read into my native calendar.

I am pretty new to objective-c but I am trying to read in both 0700 into the start time of an event and 1300 into the end time of an event. I just cant get the 1300. Mainly I want to store the first WORD "0700" and the second WORD "1300".

EDIT:
If possible please include code that converts the string "0700 1400" to a string will later be the time interval of

`EKEvent *myEvent;`

This is the code I use to store the data within the text file I'm downloading from the web.

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:downloadFile.receivedData];
NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
[self.myDataArray addObject:dataString];
```

`myDataArray` is a mutable array which I initiated earlier in `viewDidLoad` of my current view controller.

This is a small snippet of the textfile im reading in.

```
Sunday
0 1200
Sunday
2100 2400
Monday
0 600
```

Comment: First, can you post what you've tried and why it's failing (errors, invalid output, etcetera)?

Comment: just edited my question

Comment: thank you that edit was exactly what I meant haha. Where you able to find a solution? Or rather, know what Im trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to parse my text file but now the issue of converting the string that contains the start date and end date to an NSDATE.

I am not looping through the entire file yet, just one line within the specific file, i'll loop through the entire file once I can format ONE line at least.

I currently have converted 0 and 1200 to `2013-06-08 00:00:00 +0000 and 2013-06-08 12:00:00 +0000` by appending and inserting.

Heres the code I used.

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:downloadFile.receivedData];
NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSArray *components = [dataString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
NSString *anotherString = [NSString stringWithFormat:components[1]];
NSArray *times = [anotherString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];


NSMutableString *startDate = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:times[0]];
NSMutableString *endDate = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:times[1]];

for (int i = startDate.length; i < 4; i++)
    [startDate appendString:@"0"];
[startDate appendString:@":00 +0000"];

for (int i = endDate.length; i < 4; i++)
    [endDate appendString:@"0"];
[endDate appendString:@":00 +0000"];


[startDate insertString:@":" atIndex:2];
[endDate insertString:@":" atIndex:2];

[startDate insertString:@"2013-06-08 " atIndex:0];
[endDate insertString:@"2013-06-08 " atIndex:0];
```

I realized that when adding events, I don't need to know the end time just the time interval. So i plan on taking the start TIME and comparing it to the end TIME and find the time interval that way.

I understand the DATE i give my string is of a constant date but that isn't the issue at the moment, I'll fix that later. But for now I would like to convert the NSString *startDate I created and stored the date/time string in to an NSDate *startDate so that I can use it as the start dat of an EKEvent.

Thank you guys.